# Is $Y^2-X^3+X$ a variety?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

My question is whether $F=Y^2-X^3+X \in k[X,Y] $ ($k$ :algebraically closed) is an irreducible variety or not. It suffices to show that F is irreducible as we have a plane curve. Writing F as $F=(y+f(x))(y+g(x)) $ we can conclude that $f^2(x)=(x^2+1)x=(x+i)(x-i)x$. Doesn't that mean that $V(F)$ is irreducible? I am confused because if you see geometrically the curve you will see it's a non-connected shape: [image]

Isn't every variety suppose to be connected? Topologically every irreducible set is a connected set so doesn't that mean the same geometrically?

Comment: This is an elliptic curve. It is connected in the Zariski topology.

Answer (score 1):

A real subvariety (irreducible nonempty algebraic subset) of $\Bbb A^k(\Bbb R)$ may be disconnected in the "classical" topology, as this shows.
Nonetheless it is connected in the Zariski topology, which is much coarser.
The closed sets in the Zariski topology are those defined by algebraic equations.

If you split this curve into two distinct pieces, $C_1$ and $C_2$
as illustrated above, then $C_2$ is contained in the Zariski closure of $C_1$. This means that any polynomial vanishing on $C_1$ also vanishes on $C_2$.

Comment: I do understand that Zariski topology is essentially different from the euclidean but still i would think that the variety above, being irreducible would mean that the 2 shapes intersect somehow. I thought for example that they do intersect on the imaginary plane, difficult though it may be to imagine If no such thing occurs, is there any geometric interpretation to what a closed irreducible set in zariski topology looks like?

Comment: It appears disconnected because you're only looking at the $\mathbb R$-valued points. If you look at this equation over $\mathbb C$ it looks like a torus with a point or two missing.